# Delimiter Trouble

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, delimiter

Fairly new to databases and am using mysql 8.0. I am trying to change my delimiter for a stored procedure but it keeps telling me that create is expected. Not sure why. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
This is my code for the procedure.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE CustomerInfo 
(
    CustomerFirstName     CHAR (20),
    CustomerLastName      CHAR (20),
    CustomerAddress       CHAR (100),
    CustomerState         CHAR (20),
    CustomerZip           INT(5),
    CustomerPhoneNumber   CHAR (15),
    CustomerEmailAddress  CHAR (50)
 )   


BEGIN

  INSERT INTO Customers
  (CustomerFirstName,CustomerLastName,CustomerAddress,CustomerState,CustomerZip,CustomerPhoneNumber,CustomerEmailAddress)
  
  VALUES
  (CustomerFirstName, CustomerLastName, CustomerAddress, CustomerState, CustomerZip, CustomerPhoneNumber, CustomerEmailAddress);

INSERT INTO Invoice
  (CustomerFirstName,CustomerLastName,CustomerAddress,CustomerState,CustomerZip,CustomerPhoneNumber,CustomerEmailAddress)
  
  VALUES
  (CustomerFirstName, CustomerLastName, CustomerAddress, CustomerState, CustomerZip, CustomerPhoneNumber, CustomerEmailAddress);
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Don't give parameters the same names as columns.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j3MnKYwTfDkit2utzfuk8k/0 or on my server - is there information missing from your question , what ide are you using (if any)

Comment: Thank you  P.Salmon. Good idea. I was trying to use the create procedure when you right click stored procedures in mysql. When I put in query it worked fine.